# launching an activity from a broadcast receiver that listens to outgoing call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to launch an activity from a broadcast receiver that listens to outgoing call which is 5556. The problem is, the activity is not being launched but the dial inbuilt activity is being called, I have changed the priority of the intent to 100 but to no avail. How do I get the activity to launch at dial instead of the inbuilt calling activity?
Here is the code:

```
package com.messageHider;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class launchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String number=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        String compare_num="5556";
        if(number.equals(compare_num))
        {
            Intent myintent=new Intent(context,messageHider.class);
            myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(myintent);
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".launchReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="0">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Did you ever come right?

Answer (score 3):

In your manifest you require one permission (according to the docs):

> You must hold the PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission to receive this
>   Intent.

And that is

```
"android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"
```

Also straight from the docs:

> Any BroadcastReceiver receiving this Intent must not abort the broadcast.

And here is the link to the page where I got the info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: The intent sent is `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`. The intent is sent by the system. When you receive it, you would get `EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER` from the intent data, then you need to set the `resultData` to null if you want your app to handle the call, or you can change the phone number and the system will handle the new number. I haven't used it in awhile, but that's what I'm getting from the docs. Does that help? If not, exactly what example code do you want?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of aborting broadcast with  abortBroadcast(); use setResultData(null) to end the call after launching your activity.