# Launch an activity on pressing a number on dial pad

Tags: android

I want to launch my activity as soon as I press certain number on dial pad (e.g #123#).
The whole scenario is-
1- User press certain keys on dial pad.
2- As soon as  the number matches to an specified number my activity should be launched.
3- The dial pad must go off the screen.

Help please.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check it out :
[launching an activity from a broadcast receiver that listens to outgoing call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402679/launching-an-activity-from-a-broadcast-receiver-that-listens-to-outgoing-call)

```
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {   

  if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
   String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER );
   Log.i(TAG , "Received Outgoing Call");
     if(phoneNumber.equals("#*12345*#")) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context , MainActivity.class);
        Log.i(TAG , "Starting ShaDoW Main Activity");
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
        context.startActivity(intent1); 
   }
```

Comment: In this case I have to press call button to make an outgoing call.  My case is on number press.